# eclipse server(tomcat) could not find servlet on startup, although native tomcat runs fine when project is deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

> INFO: Marking servlet MyServlet as unavailable Jun 02, 2015 12:04:05
>   PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup SEVERE:
>   Servlet /MyProject threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mycompany.myproject.servlet.MyServlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  Jun 02, 2015 12:04:05 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] Jun 02, 2015 12:04:05 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] Jun 02, 2015 12:04:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   9837 ms

This is the console when I deploy my project in eclipse's server(tomcat).It does not create class files of .java files.But when I deployed my project's .war file in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps ,it runs fine.
I have searched everywhere on the internet,tried changing eclipse's preference, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Don't have time to make a response but you need to go to your Project Properties then Deployment Assembly and make sure your sources and resources have the deploy path "WEB-INF/classes", your web content have the deploy path "/" and your libs have the deploy path "WEB-INF/lib".

Comment: src and WebContent was already set. Added deploy path for every jar,problem still exists

Comment: Do you use Maven to manage your project build ?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear in the error.

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myproject.servlet.MyServlet
```

Make sure that class file is present in `WEB-INF/classes` folder in that particular path. Sometimes it could be a result of simple typo-mistake in the `web.xml` file. Recheck it for any mistakes.

Comment: None typo-mistake. I am telling you, project runs fine when I deploy my project's .war file explicitly in tomcat directory(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps)

Comment: I don't know why eclipse doesn't compile any .java files. But running tomcat explicity works fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your eclipse internal webapps folder called wtpwebapps. Double
  click on your tomcat7 folder to display the overview. it should be under -> workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps

[image]

- Double check that you have permisions in that folder and eclipse is compiling them under .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\MyProject\WEB-INF\classes
- On your package explorer go to your tomcat7 configuration and open your server.xml you should see something like:

If you don't check permisions or try to create the server configuration from the beggining.

```
<Context docBase="MyProject" path="/MyProject" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject"/></Host>
```

Comment: I found this in C:\Users\myusername\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\conf\server.xml :
`<Context docBase="C:\Users\myusername\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\MyOtherProject" path="/MyOtherProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyOtherProject"/><Context docBase="C:\Users\myusername\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\MyProject" path="/MyProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject"/></Host>`

Comment: changed `reloadable="true"` to `false` , getting same exception in both